# cannot boot window 7 after installing ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: dual-boot

At first, i had  two operating system

```
1>window 8 pro  
2>window 7 ultimate(installed by OEM)
```

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 and made my usb drive bootable for ubuntu. After pressing F12 in boot menu i selected (3> usb memory priority ) third option and while installing  process it gave me option to install it. One of them was as(remove window 8 and install ubuntu). I selected that one. After installing ubuntu when i restarted my computer there is no option for window 7 (i can't boot my window 7 )

I am not able to boot into Windows 7. How to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check using gparted which partitions you have?

Also you can install grub customizer to try to add your windows 7 to the grub list.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```